# in MapKit iOS 8, how to detect when view has stopped moving?

Tags: ios8, delegates, mapkit

I've looked all over in the docs, here, and asking around.   I have a task that fetches over the net (from Cloud Kit) and so that qualifies as an "expensive" task, something I don't want to do in -mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:

I also tried -mapView:mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap:, but that's not the right answer either.

The MKMapView itself, as well as its superview, the UIViewController's view property, both return nil for -gestureRecognizers

I have no idea at this point what the right trigger is to kick off the expensive operation when the Map is no longer moving/scrolling.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a case for GCD - Grand Central Dispatch, that can help you to manage your app syncronization queues.
[See GCD documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html)